# I'm having trouble connecting to mqtt in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, mqtt

I'm having trouble connecting to mqtt in flutter. I can't connect. The code I am using is as follows.

```
import 'package:mqtt_client/mqtt_server_client.dart';

late MqttServerClient client;

// ignore: camel_case_types
class mqttconnect {
  Future<MqttServerClient> connect() async {
    try {
      client =
          MqttServerClient.withPort('broker.emqx.io', 'flutter_client', 1883);
      client.logging(on: true);
      client.onConnected = onConnected;
      client.onDisconnected = onDisconnected;
    } catch (e) {
      print(e.toString());
    }

    try {
      await client.connect();
    } catch (e) {
      print('Exception: $e');
      client.disconnect();
    }

    return client;
  }

  void onConnected() {
    print('object');
  }

  void onDisconnected() {}
}
```

[image]

While trying to connect to mqtt, I get an error as above in the console. How can I fix.

Comment: How does this differ from your other question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70701853/i-cannot-establish-a-successful-connection-to-mqtt-in-flutter)? You can [edit] tags if needed. Also please do not post images of text, they are impossible to search, hard to read and of no use to people who need to use screen readers. Post the actual text and then format it.

Answer (score 0):

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:developer';
import 'package:mqtt_client/mqtt_client.dart';
import 'package:mqtt_client/mqtt_server_client.dart';

late MqttServerClient client;

mqttSubscribe() async {
  client = MqttServerClient.withPort("broker.emqx.io", "daly", 1883);
  client.keepAlivePeriod = 30;
  client.autoReconnect = true;
  await client.connect().onError((error, stackTrace) {
    log("error -> " + error.toString());
  });

  client.onConnected = () {
    log('MQTT connected');
  };

  client.onDisconnected = () {
    log('MQTT disconnected');
  };

  client.onSubscribed = (String topic) {
    log('MQTT subscribed to $topic');
  };

  if (client.connectionStatus!.state == MqttConnectionState.connected) {
    client.subscribe("battery", MqttQos.atMostOnce);

    client.updates!.listen((List<MqttReceivedMessage<MqttMessage?>>? c) {
      final recMess = c![0].payload as MqttPublishMessage;
      final pt = MqttPublishPayload.bytesToStringAsString(recMess.payload.message);
      log("message payload => " + pt);
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:mqtt_client/mqtt_client.dart';
import 'package:mqtt_client/mqtt_server_client.dart';



class MqttService{
   MqttService._();


  /// Our mqtt client object.
  static late MqttClient client;
  
  // for listen from other pages.
  // and can close listen mqtt.
  static StreamSubscription? mqttListen; 


  static void initMqtt(){
     
    /// Initialize Mqtt and connect.
    client = MqttServerClient(/* Your mqtt host address */)
        ..logging(on: false)
        ..port = MqttConstants.mqttPort
        ..keepAlivePeriod = 20
        ..onDisconnected = _onDisconnected
        ..onSubscribed = _onSubscribed
        ..onConnected = _onConnected
        ..onUnsubscribed = _onUnsubscribed
        ..onSubscribeFail = _onSubscribeFail;

     /// If the mqtt connection lost
     /// MqttBroker publish this message on this topic.
     final mqttMsg = MqttConnectMessage()
        .withWillMessage('connection-failed')
        .withWillTopic('willTopic')
        .startClean()
        .withWillQos(MqttQos.atLeastOnce)
        .withWillTopic('failed');
    client.connectionMessage = mqttMsg;
    await _connectMqtt();
  }


   /// Mqtt server connected.
  void _onConnected() {
    log('Connected');
    _listenMqtt();
  }

  /// Mqtt server disconnected
  void _onDisconnected() {
    log('Disconnected');
  }

  /// Mqtt server subscribed
  void _onSubscribed(String? topic) {
    log('Subscribed topic is : $topic');
  }

  void _onUnsubscribed(String? topic) {
    log('Unsubscribed topic is : $topic');
  }

  void _onSubscribeFail(String? topic) {
    log('Failed subscribe topic : $topic');
  }


  /// Connection MQTT Server.
  Future<void> _connectMqtt() async {
    if (client.connectionStatus!.state != MqttConnectionState.connected) {
      try {
        await client.connect();
      } catch (e) {
        log('Connection failed' + e.toString());
      }
    } else {
      log('MQTT Server already connected ');
    }
  }

  /// Diconnection MQTT Server.
  static Future<void> disconnectMqtt() async {
    if (client.connectionStatus!.state == MqttConnectionState.connected) {
      try {
        client.disconnect();
      } catch (e) {
        log('Disconnection Failed ' + e.toString());
      }
    } else {
      log('MQTT Server already disconnected ');
    }
  }
  

  /// Subscribe a topic
  static void subscribeTopic(String topic) {
    final state = client.connectionStatus?.state;
    if (state != null) {
      if (state == MqttConnectionState.connected) {
        client.subscribe(topic + "/data", MqttQos.atLeastOnce);
      }
    }
  }

  /// Publish a message to topic 
  /// [reatain] means last message save the broker.
  static void publish(String topic, String message, {bool retain = true}) {
    final builder = MqttClientPayloadBuilder();
    builder.addString(message);
    client.publishMessage(
      topic,
      MqttQos.atLeastOnce,
      builder.payload!,
      retain: retain,
    );
    builder.clear();
  }


  static void unSubscribeTopic(String topic) {
    final state = client.connectionStatus?.state;
    if (state != null) {
      if (state == MqttConnectionState.connected) {
        client.unsubscribe(topic + "/data");
      }
    }
  }

 
  static void onClose(){
    mqttListen?.close();
    disconnectMqtt();
  }

  void _listenMqtt() {
    mqttListen = client.updates!.listen((dynamic t) {
      MqttPublishMessage recMessage = t[0].payload;
      final message =
          MqttPublishPayload.bytesToStringAsString(recMessage.payload.message);
      /*
        Listen subscribe topic.
      */
      log(message);
    });
  }


}
```

I have created a nice format for `MQTT` and I wanted to share with you through this question.

Package: [mqtt_client](https://pub.dev/packages/mqtt_client)